# Java Quotation Matching

Tags: java, string

I'm not sure if this is a regex question, but i need to be able to grab whats inside single qoutes, and surround them with something. For example:

```
this is a 'test' of 'something' and 'I' 'really' want 'to' 'solve this'
```

would turn into

```
this is a ('test') of ('something') and ('I') ('really') want ('to') ('solve this')
```

Any help you could provide would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: What should happen if there are escaped single quotes inside the string?

Comment: @Mark - that shouldn't make a difference in this case. `"'a'"` is equal to `"\'a\'"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String str = "this is a 'test' of 'something'";
String rep = str.replaceAll("'[^']*'", "($0)"); // stand back, I know regex
```

What I did here is use toe `replaceAll()` method which searches for all matches for regex `"'[^']*'"` and replaces them with regex `"($0)"`.

The pattern `"'[^']*'"` matches all substrings that start and end with a single quote (`'`), and between them are any characters, except another single quote (`[^']`), and those can appear any number of times (`*`). Replacing those with `"($0)"` means taking every match (`$0`) and wrapping it with parenthesis.

Comment: Do you mind including a couple of lines explaining it? Thanks ;]

Answer (score 0):

One easy way (but not always valid) is the following
If always you have [ '] and [' ] , you can do this:

```
myString.replace(" '"," ('"); // replaces all <space_apostrophe> with <space_bracket_apostrophe>
```

Do the same for the rear bracket :)

---

One more thing - why do you even have apostrophes-surrounded words? Is it a must that they must be like that? If you made them like that, why did you do it and then look for another approach !

Answer (score -1):

If you can ignore single apostrophes, you could do like this (C# code, should be easy to translate)

```
string input = "this is a 'test' of 'something' and ...";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(input, "'([^']*)'", "('$1')"));
```

Comment: lol, posting C# is that bad? This code can't help OP to find a way to solve his problem?